# Error parsing a specific JSON file in Snowflake with File Format

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a Stage and File Format in Snowflake which works with all my other JSON files except this, which throws an error:

> Error parsing JSON: misplaced { File 'rooms.json.gz', line 1,
> character 2 Row 0, column $1

I am using the same query that I am using for other files.

```
SELECT $1
FROM @MySchema.MY_STAGE/rooms.json.gz
;
```

What is wrong with the structure of this specific JSON file?

```
{
"rooms": [
    {
        "area": 131.49,
        "longDescription": "",
        "dateCreated": 1589908063390,
        "reservable": false,
        "name": "E249",
        "remoteInfo": "",
        "description": "",
        "id": 2,
        "type": {
            "hexColor": "c16058",
            "contentFlag": 1,
            "cost": 0.0,
            "dateCreated": 1308610520717,
            "color": {},
            "name": "BREAK ROOM",
            "occupiable": false,
            "id": 120,
            "parkingSpace": false,
            "dateUpdated": 1591818585913,
            "typeCode": ""
        },
        "floor": {
            "area": 25312.9878,
            "dateCreated": 1589907703870,
            "drawingAvailable": true,
            "interiorGross": 0.0,
            "name": "2",
            "leaseArea": 0.0,
            "id": 12,
            "building": {
                "address": {
                    "country": {
                        "defaultSelected": true,
                        "subdivisionCategoryName": "state",
                        "alpha2Code": "US",
                        "isoCode": "US",
                        "name": "United States of America (the)",
                        "id": 223
                    },
                    "city": "Some City",
                    "street": "Some Drive",
                    "postalCode": "00000",
                    "state": {
                        "country": {
                            "defaultSelected": true,
                            "subdivisionCategoryName": "state",
                            "alpha2Code": "US",
                            "isoCode": "US",
                            "name": "United States of America (the)",
                            "id": 223
                        },
                        "defaultSelected": false,
                        "code": "XX",
                        "name": "Some State",
                        "id": 66,
                        "categoryName": "state"
                    }
                },
                "code": "B2",
                "dateCreated": 1589907508020,
                "metric": false,
                "name": "Some name",
                "location": {},
                "revitLink": "",
                "id": 45,
                "dateUpdated": 1601315841453,
                "costCenters": []
            },
            "dateUpdated": 1600441936663
        },
        "capacity": 0,
        "dateUpdated": 1600441936960
    }
]
```

}

Edit: Screenshot from Notepad++ with all characters enabled
[image]

Comment: Are you certain that there isn't some dodgy, non-printing character in the first/second line?

Comment: @NickW: Yes, I don't see any other characters. I've updated the screenshot in my original post.

Comment: Can you share a file that parses correctly? And the file format?

Comment: I dropped the Stage and recreated it and uploaded the same file and surprisingly it worked this time. Thanks for looking into this @FelipeHoffa. :-)

Comment: Good to know! Let's close this question then so more people don't try to answer it :)

Comment: I am not getting the option to Close this. It is looking for two more Votes to be closed.